how to flip a bar chart in powerpoint from ltr to rtl using vba code
I have charts that read from left to right, I want to flip it and read from right to left, I will provide the before and after of how I want it to be and the code in vba that I used but didn't do the job. Thank you
enter image description here
enter image description here
these pictures show I want it, right now I'm stuck with the first picture and I want to have the outcome from the last picture, I used vba code to do it but didn't succeed

Sub AdjustYAxisForArabic()
Dim pptPresentation As Presentation
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptShape As Shape
Dim pptChart As Chart
Dim pptChartAxis As Axis
Dim pptPath As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim folder As Object
Dim file As Object
Dim logFile As String
Dim fileNum As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Select the folder path where your PowerPoint files are located
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            pptPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    logFile = pptPath & "\Log.txt"
    fileNum = FreeFile()
    
    Open logFile For Append As #fileNum
    Print #fileNum, "Processing started at " & Now()
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(pptPath)
    
    Dim processedFiles As Integer
    processedFiles = 0
    
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(file.Name)) = "pptx" Then
    
            Set pptPresentation = Application.Presentations.Open(file.Path)
            For Each pptSlide In pptPresentation.Slides
                For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
                    If pptShape.HasChart Then
                        Set pptChart = pptShape.Chart
    
                        ' Move Y-axis to the right side
                        If pptChart.HasAxis(xlValue) Then
                            Set pptChartAxis = pptChart.Axes(xlValue)
                            If Not pptChartAxis Is Nothing Then
                                ' Center align the Y-axis title
                                If pptChartAxis.HasTitle Then
                                    pptChartAxis.AxisTitle.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                                End If
                                
                                ' Move axis to the right
                                pptChartAxis.TickLabelPosition = ppAxisTickLabelPositionNextToAxis
                                pptChartAxis.ReversePlotOrder = False
                                pptChartAxis.TickLabels.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
                                pptChartAxis.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
                                pptChartAxis.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)  ' Black color
                            End If
                        End If
    
                        ' Adjust X-axis for right-to-left reading
                        If pptChart.HasAxis(xlCategory) Then
                            Set pptChartAxis = pptChart.Axes(xlCategory)
                            If Not pptChartAxis Is Nothing Then
                                pptChartAxis.ReversePlotOrder = True
                                pptChartAxis.TickLabels.Orientation = ppHorizontal
                            End If
                        End If
    
                        ' Adjust plot area
                        pptChart.PlotArea.InsideLeft = pptChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth * 0.1
                        pptChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth = pptChart.PlotArea.InsideWidth * 0.8
                    End If
                Next pptShape
            Next pptSlide
    
            pptPresentation.Save
            pptPresentation.Close
    
            Print #fileNum, "Processed: " & file.Name
    
            processedFiles = processedFiles + 1
        End If
    Next file
    
    Print #fileNum, "Processing completed at " & Now()
    Print #fileNum, processedFiles & " files were processed successfully."
    Close #fileNum
    
    MsgBox "Mission Accomplished! " & processedFiles & " files were processed.", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number \<\> 0 Then
Print #fileNum, "Error processing file: " & file.Name
Print #fileNum, "Error description: " & Err.Description
MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & \_
"File: " & file.Name, vbCritical
End If

    If Not pptPresentation Is Nothing Then
        pptPresentation.Close
        Set pptPresentation = Nothing
    End If
    
    Resume Next

End Sub

help please
I tried vba code on powerpoint expecting to change the layout of a bar chart from left to right to right to left, I'm using pptxgenjs to create the charts

Pls try pptChartAxis.ReversePlotOrder = True

I tried it, but I get the values reversed, it used to be from top to bottom, it becomes from bottom to top

I meant  pptChart.Axes(xlValue).ReversePlotOrder = True.

Thanks a lot for the recommendation, it worked, https://ibb.co/HTZfTht
only a small issue, that the 0% is a bit in the words.
Thanks a lot <3

the 0% is a bit in the words - may i know what does it mean?

I figured it out, thanks a lot for the help my friend, I wanted the label to be a bit away from the chart
